# Why is $|\sigma(\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_N\})|\leq 2^{2^N}$?

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to understand mathematically why $|\sigma(\mathcal{M})|\leq 2^{2^{N}}$  where $\mathcal{M}=\{A_{1},A_{2},\dots,A_{N}\}$ is a finite system of subsets of $X$. I found this [below Definition 3 on page 1](http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~maxeh/P3LectureNotes.pdf). If the proof is hard, so please avoid  taking your time on proving it since I am not really good at understanding some proofs in this subject.

There is no problem for me to imagine how the $\sigma$-algebra of a system of a single set of $X$ looks like. It is kind of hard to imagine a $\sigma$-algebra of a system of sets of $X$.

If we have $N=1$, then $\sigma(\{A_{1}\})=\{\emptyset,A_{1},X\setminus A_{1},X\}=\mathcal{P}(X)$.
It would be problematic if we construct a $\sigma$-algebra for $N=2$, since we don't know how $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ look like. If we assume that $\{A_{1},A_{2}\}$ is a  set parition of $X$, then we have $\sigma(\{A_{1},A_{2}\})=\mathcal{P}(X)$.

How would the construction of $\sigma$-algebra look like without trying constructing one if $A_{1}\cap A_{2}\neq \emptyset$? For example, is there a system that contains $\sigma(\{A_{1},A_{2}\})$? I agree that are many sets in $\sigma(\{A_{1},A_{2}\})$.

My incomplete imagination is $\sigma(\{A_{1},A_{2}\})\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)\subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\{A_{1},A_{2}\}))$ and then I would conclude that 
$$|\sigma(\{A_{1},A_{2}\})|\leq |\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\{A_{1},A_{2}\}))|=2^{|\mathcal{P}(\{A_{1},A_{2}\})|}\leq 2^{2^{2}}.$$

I just feel like $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\{A_{1},A_{2}\}))$ isn't a good idea, since there are some elements of itself that have nothing to do with $\sigma(\{A_{1},A_{2}\})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $E$ is an *atom* if $$E=\bigcap_{j=1}^NB_j,$$where for every $j$ either $B_j=A_j$ or $B_j=A_j^c$. (Those need not be "real" atoms; call them that anyway.) There are at most $2^N$ atoms. You can check that the set of finite unions of atoms (including the empty union) is an algebra; hence it's the algebra generated by $A_1,\dots,A_N$, which hence has no more than $2^{2^N}$ elements.

Comment: To your last sentence, "... hence it's the algebra generated by $A_1 ,…, A_N$, which hence has no more than $2^{2^N}$ elements." How exactly do you know that it has no more than $2^{2^N}$ elements?

Comment: You believe the rest of it - there are at most $2^N$ atoms, and every element of the algebra is a union of atoms? Fine. Now if $S$ has $k$ elements how many subsets does $S$ have?

Comment: There are $2^{k}$ subsets of $S$.

Comment: Ok... so how many sets of atoms are there?

Comment: There would be $2^{2^k}$, but I just don't understand it. It's like to determine $|\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(S))|$.

Comment: I hope there was a typo in your last comment. Yes, it's exactly like that! If $S=\{A_1,\dots,A_N\}$ then an atom is defined in terms of an element of $P(S)$, and hence an element of the algebra is defined in terms of an element of $P(P(S))$.